# Create subgraph of LEMON ListDigraph in c++

Tags: c++, mapping, graph-theory, lemon-graph-library

I have a ListDigraph and related node and arc maps, namely,

```
ListDigraph::ArcMap<int>length;
ListDigraph::NodeMap<int> label;
```

I have a list of nodes, belonging to the graph. I would like to build a subgraph which has list of nodes mentioned before.

I'm using the LEMON library, but I cannot find a nice solution for it.

I used the reference here: http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/tutorial/a00009.html but actually this does not help, for Digraphs it does not accept both arc and node maps in the copy of the graph.

Is there a simple solution that given a list of node I want to maintain, I can obtain the subgraph with only those nodes together with the arcs connected to them (unless the other end of the arc belonged to a now-erased node) ? Of course, also the edge map should be preserve: the label (length) on the arcs must remain.

Comment: "giving for each node a list of nodes that maintain a given property."  ???  Maybe you mean "for each property a list of nodes that maintain that property"  Or maybe " for each node a list of nodes that maintain the same property."

Comment: no, I meant what I said: I have the nodes. then I have a map that has the node_id as key and a vector of node_ids as value. The node_ids in the vectors respect a property regarding the key node_id. In this specific example, are all the nodes in a given radious from a given source

Comment: "respect a property" What does it mean to respect a property?

Comment: It is not so important, I'll edit the question, we're going out of focus here

Comment: It is very important to be clear.  Fuzzy writing leads to fuzzy thinking and answers that are confused or wrong

Comment: That is better, but still confusing.  I think you mean "a subgraph of the input graph that contains only a given subset of the nodes in the input graph"

Comment: yep, exactly. I just want to build a subgraph given a set of nodes I want to maintain. But I want to avoid to build this graph from beginning

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the input graph, call it g2
- LOOP N over nodes in g2

  - If N NOT in nodes subset to be maintained

    - REMOVE from g2 all edges connected to N
    - REMOVE N from g2
- RETURN g2

Comment: wouldn't be too costly ?

Comment: There is no cheaper way

Comment: I would like to use a StatiGraph which is less costly, but I cannot if I have to remove nodes

Comment: Can you ADD nodes to a StatiGraph?  If so, then you could use one, but the algorithm is then more complicated.  The saving from using a StatiGraph would have to be large to compensate.  If you think it might be worthwhile, you will have to test both and find out.